# Appropriate statistical tests (hypotheses) for categorical and numeric values on a specific dataset in R

Tags: r, anova, t-test

I am new to statistics and I was hoping someone could guide me on what statistical tests I should complete in R on the following dataset. I am trying to investigate the relationship between births and the issue of a specific drug to treat postnatal depression.

**The data set was created as follows:**

- I obtained the number of births in Northern Ireland in 2021 grouped by Month of birth and local council area (LCA).
- I also obtained a dataset that contained a list of all the times a particular anti-depressant (used to treat postnatal depression) was issued by doctors in Northern Ireland in 2021.
- I groups filtered the prescription by Month and Local Council Area and created a new file

**This resulted in a dataset that contained:**

- Month of 2021
- Local Council Area (LCA)
- Number of prescriptions of this depressant per council area, per month
- Number of live births in a council area per month

**Below is a sample of the table:**

| Month.of.Birth.in.2021 | LCA | Number.Births | Number.Prescriptions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | Antrim and Newtownabbey | 135 | 4300 |
| January | Armagh City, Banbridge and Craigavon | 215 | 7571 |
| January | Belfast | 333 | 16866 |
| January | Ards and North Down | 118 | 4423 |
| February | Antrim and Newtownabbey | 105 | 4118 |
| February | Armagh City, Banbridge and Craigavon | 205 | 7295 |
| February | Belfast | 301 | 16251 |

Full dataset link is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qvm34S76g2oyXuf44PY2-xnvxvHg9Z7T/view?usp=sharing

I have completed many visualisations of the data but I am unsure on the follows:

- which statistical test to use
- why this test should be used
- what hypothesis to test with this statistical test

I have looked at numerous videos and blogs, but am unsure how to apply this knowledge to this particular dataset.

Any help or guidance would be greatly apprecaited.

I have tried a T-Test (one and two sample), a F Test to compare two variances however I am unsure of what the results mean for the data that I am using.

Comment: What research question are you hoping to answer? What is your hypothesis/reason for thinking there would be some form of association between the two variables? Are you anticipating that people are more likely to be issued anti-depressants when they have a brand new baby? Like they will receive a prescription within the same month that they have the baby?

Comment: As a general rule, in Canada, at least there's a 6 week gap between when a baby is born and when the mother is scheduled for a follow up check-in on her mental health. So you might not see a correlation within the same month (i.e., there may be a temporal offset) even if a relationship exists.

Comment: This looks like homework. If so, you should say what efforts you have put forward in answering this.

Comment: We can't tell you what *you* want to find out (what hypotheses you want to test, or even what someone else wants you to test - we don't read minds); the hypotheses are an essential part of figuring out how to test (what specific test statistics and rejection rules might make sense). "Investigate the relationship" is so vague as to suggest little more than plots and related summaries to me.